# Need to grab the highest and lowest number in adjacent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in Excel, I am attempting to show 1-4 for AAAA, 5-7 for BBBB, etc

```
Num Words
1   AAAA
2   AAAA
3   AAAA
4   AAAA
5   BBBB
6   BBBB
7   BBBB
8   CCCC
9   CCCC
10  CCCC
11  CCCC
12  CCCC
13  CCCC
14  CCCC
15  DDDD
16  DDDD
17  DDDD
18  DDDD
19  DDDD
20  DDDD
```

My logic in my head is that I would like to look at the whole column and grab the highest number of a set of adjacent cells which match the words. Thus grabbing the output described above for each word.

Thanks for any assistance.

[image: Example]

Comment: I've read this three times and still have no idea what you're asking. Are you showing an example of the input you've got in a spreadsheet or the desired output? Are we looking at the values in the first one or two columns of your spreadsheet or something else?

Comment: Are you wanting the row numbers of the start and end of identical cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume there is a header row.  In C2 put:

```
 =IF(MIN(IF(B2 = B:B, A:A))=A2, A2 & "-" & MAX(IF(B2 = B:B, A:A)),"")
```

It is an array formula and needs to be Confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.

[image]

**Note:**

If your search range is static then change all the full column references to the absolute range, e.g. A:A in this case would become $A$2:$A$21.  It will make the formulas calculate quicker.

Comment: I learned so much from this. Thanks! This definitely did the trick.

**It is an array formula and needs to be Confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copy down.**

Regarding this comment. Is there something you suggest I read to understand why I had to Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: google "how to use array formulas in excel"  .it will give you better information than I can in this limited space.  There are many great articles.  Basically it iterates through the ranges and checks the conditions on each iteration.

Comment: I googled it and got myself a bit confused. Then I played with it a bit off and on at a smaller scope and now I'm seeing clearly how the iteration works. Thanks again Scott!

Answer (score 2):

One more for the pot; the newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) produces a pseudo-MINIF/MAXIF without CSE.

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6,A:A /(B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))=E4), 1)&"-"&AGGREGATE(14, 6,A:A /(B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))=E4), 1)
```

[image: from_min_to_max_if]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1:A21, put these formulas into the sheet...

EDIT: Updates to use Array formulas, which allows for the source list to be unordered

```
'Titles
D1 : Word
E1 : Min
F1 : Max

'The {} indicate an Array formula - Enter with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

'For each word
D2 = AAAA
E2 : {=MIN(IF(D2 =B:B,A:A))}
F2 : {=MAX(IF(D2 =B:B,A:A))}

'You can just fill the above cells down, or type these formulas in:

D3 : BBBB
E2 : {=MIN(IF(D3 =B:B,A:A))}
F2 : {=MAX(IF(D3 =B:B,A:A))}

D4 : CCCC
E2 : {=MIN(IF(D4 =B:B,A:A))}
F2 : {=MAX(IF(D4 =B:B,A:A))}

D5 : DDDD
E2 : {=MIN(IF(D5 =B:B,A:A))}
F2 : {=MAX(IF(D5 =B:B,A:A))}
```

So, the results looks like:

```
Word    Min Max
AAAA      1   4
BBBB      5   7
CCCC      8  14
DDDD     15  20
```

Comment: Not even a shout out thanking me for coming up with the formula from which your new ones are derived?  I mean it is apparent that it was a literal copy paste.  With the only change being one reference cell.

Comment: Indeed, your solution got there in one edit. I revised mine a couple of times, but without seeing yours. The only copying I did was from my Worksheet cells.

Comment: I figure the OP needs to use the Min and Max in subsequent steps. Also, my approach only calculates the Min and Max once per Word.... If there are hundreds or thousands of instances of each word, or even just hundreds or thousands of rows, then minimizing the number of Min and MAx calls will improve performance.