# Excel Min Function returns 0

Tags: excel, function, min

I have already checked the Excel Documentation... I am always getting 0

this is my Excel Table[image]

And this is my Code:

```
=MIN(IF(C7="X";C20);IF(D7="X";D20))
```

and If there is an "X" in Cell C7 and D7, I want to get the SMALLEST (MIN) value of Cell C20 or D20 and it works fine, BUT --> When I remove one "X" let say in Cell D7, I only get 0 back, becasue the Min Function always returns 0, if my IF Functions are not a digit / number, but when I remove my X, i always get False back from my IF() functions....

So my question is, how could I ignore all If Return values who are not a number means, when of my IF() Functions returns false <-- how could I ignore this value, that my MIN() Function will give me a valud resulst back - and not 0

???

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What would you want to return if no "X" are found?

Comment: @Zerk: Hey Zerk, thanks for your Answer... nothing! I want to ignore the Cells who has no "X" in it!

Comment: While a [MINIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833434/need-to-grab-the-highest-and-lowest-number-in-adjacent-cells/34835097#34835097) doesn't support what I read in your narrative, it seems to answer the overall problem; e.g. minimum number when row 7 equals zero. Office 365 supports a native MINIF, see [MINIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833434/need-to-grab-the-highest-and-lowest-number-in-adjacent-cells/34835097#34835097) for an AGGREGATE pseudo-MINIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IF statements you could add a very large value to be used in the FALSE case:

```
=MIN(IF(C7="X";C20;99999);IF(D7="X";D20;99999))
```

However, this would mean that if there are no X’s then the calculated value will be 99999. But for cases where there is at least one X you’ll get the correct minimum value. Just make sure that the FALSE case value is large enough to always be greater than values in row 20.

If you wanted a specific value in case there are no X’s found, you can have a hidden cell do the calculation above, and another cell check its value. e.g.:

```
A1 = MIN(IF(C7="X";C20;99999);IF(D7="X";D20;99999))
A2 = IF(A1=99999;"No Matches";A1)
```

Or you can also combine it all into one cell if you don’t mind the complex formula:

```
= IF( MIN(IF(C7="X";C20;99999);IF(D7="X";D20;99999)) = 99999 ;
      "No Matches" ; 
      MIN(IF(C7="X";C20;99999);IF(D7="X";D20;99999)) )
```

Comment: that helped me out: =MIN(IF(C7="X";C20;99999);IF(D7="X";D20;99999))
THANKKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this formula against your scenarios and it worked for all cases:

1) X in both C7 and D7 (returns 9)
2) X in only D7 (returns 10)
3) X in only C7 (returns 9)
4) no X in C7 nor D7 (returns 0)

```
=IF(AND(C7="X",D7="X"),MIN(C20:D20),IF(COUNTIF(C7:D7,"X")>0,INDEX(C20:D20,MATCH("X",C7:D7,0)),0))
```

Comment: Holtzmann: Sorry but the problem is, when I add more then 2 COlumn into my ranges, it doenst give me the smallest number of my Range back....

Comment: this is my / Your Code who doenst work with 3 columns: =WENN(UND(C7="X";D7="X";E7="X");MIN(C20:E20);WENN(ZÄHLENWENN(C7:E7;"X")>0;INDEX(C20:E20;VERGLEICH("X";C7:E7;0));0))

Comment: "WENN" means IF ----------- "VERGLEICH" means MATCH ----------- "ZÄHLENWENN" means COUNTIF

Comment: @nbg15 - Next time, please put the full scope of your requirement in the question. It was not clear you need it to work beyond cells C & D. Either way, glad you got a workable solution :)